# Query design in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have created three queries and I need to consolidate them into a single query. They all have same foreign keys from another table. My objective is to have all the fields (primary key) from the main table displayed in the consolitated query regardless of whether there is record.

How can I acheive this?

Comment: Please edit your question to used mixed case - SHOUTING is rude.

Comment: SHOUTING is also nearly impossible to read when it goes on for more than a few words.

Comment: @Abby: i think all you need is outer joins. If you show us your queries we can show you how.

Comment: I think it will be easier to see the queries and the target query that you are trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the outline using (left) outer joins

```
select ...
from mainTable M
left join Table2 T2
on M.key=T2.key
left join Table3 T3
on M.key=T3.key
```